# Merge data from three or more identical columns of different tables into single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union, coalesce

I have three different tables with month and item as follows:
Table1

```
month books
April-2016  2
February-2016   7
January-2016    1
June-2016   6
May-2016    1
September-2015  1
```

Table2

```
month copies
April-2016  92
August-2015 1
February-2016   49
January-2016    5
June-2016   127
```

Table3

```
month pens
February-2016   74
January-2016    1
June-2016   66
March-2016  136
May-2016    128
```

Now, I was looking something like this:
month books copies pens
-the month column should be merged and other data should be placed in respective column (if no data is available then 0 should be placed) such as

```
month books copies pens
April-2016  2 92 0
September-2015  1 0 0
August-2015 0 1 0
June-2016   6 127 66
```

I tried with

```
select COALESCE(t1.Month,t2.Month,t3.Month) AS [Month],
ISNULL(t1.books,0) AS books,
ISNULL(tp.copies,0) AS copies,
ISNULL(tn.pens,0) AS pens
from  #table1 t1
full join #table t2 on t1.month=t2.month
full join #table t3 on t1.month=t3.month
```

---Union won't work as it is giving me 6 columns ( 3 for months, where i need only 1)

Comment: what's wrong with your query?

Comment: Your query is pulling data from the same table 3 times. I don't think that is what you mean to do. To be honest the reason you are having such a problem getting data out is because your design is flawed. You shouldn't have a table for each type of item. You should have a column that indicates which type of item it is.

Comment: @Sean Lange - I was hoping the intent was to insert the result into a new table...

Comment: Yep its not data extracted from various tables in a 3 temporary tables in order to so in report (there is nothing to do with the table design here...)

Comment: Your design is what is making this difficult. If you had a better design the query would be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know to do this is to extract the months as a work-table and then left join each of the source tables in turn to pick up the columns one by one.  The extraction of the months isn't necessary if you know there's an identical list of months in each table.

```
select a.month,
       t1.books,
       t2.copies,
       t3.pens
  from (
select month from table1
union
select month from table2
union
select month from table3) a
left join table1 t1
    on a.month = t1.month
left join table2 t2
    on a.month = t2.month
left join table3 t3
    on a.month = t3.month
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `full join`.  It looks like this:

```
select COALESCE(t1.Month,t2.Month,t3.Month) AS [Month],
       COALESCE(t1.books,0) AS books,
       COALESCE(t2.copies,0) AS copies,
       COALESCE(t3.pens,0) AS pens
from  #table1 t1 full join
      #table t2
      on t2.month = t1.month full join
      #table t3
      on t3.month = coalesce(t1.month, t2.month);
```

Personally, I find the `union all`/`group by` method is the perhaps the most intuitive:

```
select month,
       sum(books) as books, sum(copies) as copies, sum(pens) as pens
from ((select month, books, 0 as copies, 0 as pens from #table1
      ) union all
      (select month, 0 as books, copies, 0 as pens from #table2
      ) union all
      (select month, 0 as books, 0 as copies, pens from #table3
      )
     ) bcp
group by month;
```

The `left join` method suggested by Mike is also very reasonable; often, I prefer not to have to list each table in two places.  That can lead to an error if I'm updating the query at a later point in time.

Comment: Mike Christie & Gordon Linoff: Thanks the both approach worked out ... But, could you tell me what is the best option with query optimization (i mean, in terms of query run time... )

Comment: @LearnByExample . . . For performance, you should test both queries on your system with a reasonable size of data.  There are situations where either version would have the better performance.